# Discord Music Bot Queue Feature (it skips the in-between tracks and jumped to the last track)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, logic, audio-streaming

I'm new here. Please guide me on this famous platform XD

I'm creating a Discord music bot using Python (discord.py) and I want to add a queue feature.

Note that this uses 'interaction' for slash command instead of 'ctx'.

Firstly, I decided to modify the /play command by adding global list queue = [], and then when a user /play a query, the query will be appended to the queue. Then, I want it to play consequently.

The code looks like this:

```
await interaction.response.defer()
    source = await YTDLSource.from_url(query, loop=client.loop)
    queue.append(source)
    print(queue)
    description = "**{}**\n{}\nRequested by: {}".format(queue[-1], queue[-1].data['webpage_url'], interaction.user.mention)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Added to queue", description=description, color=0x23EBE3)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="THUMBNAIL_URL")
    await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)

    async def play_next():
        if len(queue) > 1:
            queue.pop(0)
            print(queue)
            voice_client.play(queue[0])
            description = "**{}**\n{}\nRequested by: {}".format(queue[0], queue[0].data['webpage_url'], interaction.user.mention)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Now playing", description=description, color=0x23EBE3)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="THUMBNAIL_URL")
            await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)
    
    if not voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.play(queue[0])
        description = "**{}**\n{}\nRequested by: {}".format(queue[0], queue[0].data['webpage_url'], interaction.user.mention)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Now playing", description=description, color=0x23EBE3)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="THUMBNAIL_URL")
        await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)
    elif voice_client.is_playing():
        while voice_client.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await play_next()
```

My problem is this last four line:

```
elif voice_client.is_playing():
        while voice_client.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await play_next()
```

The first track will be added and played. After the first track, the second track will play. That is no-brainer to code. But then, when a third, fourth and so on are added, that becomes a problem.
The last four lines will indicate that they will wait for the first song to finish, then they will all simultaneously try to play instead of consequently.

My logic is bad, I know. If you can't help with the coding, at least guide me with a workflow. Thank you very much in advance!

I've tried changing
`voice_client.play(queue[0])`

into
`voice_client.play(queue[0], after=lambda e: play_next())`

for example, but I end up confusing myself. Maybe I need a better workflow to visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know you said that the lambda after confuses you, but this is what I came up with:

```
async def next_song():
    if len(queue) > 1:
        queue.pop(0)
        description = "**{}**\n{}\nRequested by: {}".format(queue[0], queue[0].data['webpage_url'], interaction.user.mention)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Now playing", description=description, color=0x23EBE3)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="THUMBNAIL_URL")
        await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)
        return queue[0]

async def play_next():
    voice_client.play(next_song(), after=lambda e: play_next())
```

Instead of playing the next song directly, It's better to make the function to fetch the next song and then return it to a recursive function that plays the next song based on what `next_song()` returns.

Note that I don't know if the `play_next()` function works as I have no way to check right now, it's just an idea of what it should be like. But if it does not work and you really want to make it work you could reach out to me on discord (DawoleQ#3486) and we can figure something out.

I hope I at least gave you an idea of how this could work.

Comment: Thanks for replying @DawoleQ . It seems like it doesn't work. I don't remember exactly the error. I think it's something like, the file is a data type and not an audio type., if I'm not mistaken. I will add you on Discord.

Edit: Did you change your Discord username? I can't add you

Comment: Ah yes sorry, it's DawoleQ#3486